# yii CHtml::button and POST request to controller

Tags: yii

Is there a way to have `CHtml::button` send a post request to the controller

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('Button Text', array('submit' => array('controller/action'))); ?>
```

I'm looking to replicate the `CHtml::link`functionality and POST to the controller

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Delete',"#", array("submit"=>array('delete', 'id'=>$data->ID), 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?')); ?>
```

EDIT:

The button is NOT submitting a form

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#submitButton-detail

Comment: this isn't a form submit, so there is no parent form data...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo CHtml::button('Delete',
    array(
        'submit'=>array('controllername/actionname',array('id'=>$id)),
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?'
        // or you can use 'params'=>array('id'=>$id)
    )
);
```

As you'll see `button` also takes the special `htmlOptions` attribute [`clientChange`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail).

**Update** Clarification of `submit`, from the [doc link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail) ():

> submit: string, specifies the URL to submit to. If the current element has a parent form, that form will be submitted, and if 'submit' is non-empty its value will replace the form's URL. **If there is no parent form the data listed in 'params' will be submitted instead (via POST method), to the URL in 'submit' or the currently requested URL if 'submit' is empty.** Please note that if the 'csrf' setting is true, the CSRF token will be included in the params too.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

As you mentioned that you want to hit the delete action, the default gii generated `actionDelete` expects the `id` in the url, hence I passed the id in the url, i.e `submit` option.

Comment: I'm not trying to submit a form, just trying to hit the delete action via the POST method. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, absolutely, typing update to answer, see in 2 mins. edit: code remains the same incase you are using the default delete action

Comment: Downvoter, if you see this, please explain your downvote, maybe i can improve on this answer.